# Apply an event on a node's child with 'this'

Tags: jquery, events, dom

I have a function that dynamically creates div boxes and put an event on them. In the box I create an a-node and inside that an img-node. When I click the a-node the event shall fire and the background image shall be changed on another div. Below you can see my code, and as it it now, 'this.src' points to the a-node, which of course doesn't work.

Is there a way to point at the a-node's child, ie. the img-node on that line?

```
var box = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'imgDiv',
    'width': maxWidth,
    'height': maxHeight,
}).appendTo('.windowContent');

var a = $('<a/>', {
    'href': '#',
}).appendTo(box)

var img = $('<img/>', {
    'src': 'pics/' + this.fileName,
    'width': this.thumbWidth,
    'height': this.thumbHeight,
}).appendTo(a);

$(a).click(function() {
    $('#desktop').css("background-image", "url(" + this.src + ")");  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` will indeed point to the anchor that was clicked inside of the click handler. There's nothing you can do about that, but your click handler will form a closure over your `img` variable.

Is this what you want?

```
$(a).click(function() {
    $('#desktop').css("background-image", "url(" + img.attr("src") + ")");  
});
```

**EDIT**

As Felix points out, a is already a jQuery object, so you can simply do:

```
a.click(function() {
    $('#desktop').css("background-image", "url(" + img.attr("src") + ")");  
});
```

Comment: That would be `img.attr('src')`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Note that `a` is already a jQuery object (so there is not need to pass it to jQuery again).

Comment: @JasonCraig - are you sure your `img` is being created properly?

Comment: Works like a charm when using img.attr('src'). Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jason, you might want to update your question to specify the AJAX calls to allow people a better view to answer your question properly.

Comment: @FelixKling has also made a good point about the `$(a)` being `a` more than likely.

Comment: @FelixKling - yes, thank you.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: How does `img.attr("src")` target the child `img` element of the clicked `a`? Wouldn't that pick up any `img` element in the dom?

Comment: @jk. img is an object OP created this click handler.  I was grabbing **that** img's source.  If I had said $("img").attr("src"); then it would grab some random src off the dom like you said

Comment: OK, got it. So it's a one and done then. He won't be repeating this on the same page.

Comment: @jk - It works because this works: http://jsfiddle.net/kJXVU/ This explains it in a way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Emulating_private_methods_with_closures

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do with this:

```
a.click(function() {
    var $imgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
    $('#desktop').css("background-image", "url(" + $imgSrc + ")");  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do:

```
$(a).click(function() {
    $('#desktop').css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).find("img").attr("src") + ")");  
});
```

Comment: That's not what I meant ;) `$(this)` is correct, but you can change `$(a)` to `a`.